# How to approach this simple problem - hiding product groups from users

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, relationship, myisam

So I have a database that has a structure something like this:

```
[user_table] user_id, name, active
"john", "John S. Smith", true

[group_table] group_id, description, active
"abc", "test group", "true"
"cba", "second group", "true"
"bca", "third group", "true"
```

So now I would like to hide "abc" group from "john".
I create a new table called "hide_group" with field user_id and group_id. I insert appropriate values and everything is nice. But it is not very well optimized. What if I have 20 users and hundreds of groups? That would mean hundreds of new records.
Is there a more optimized way to do this with relationships? I am using MyISAM engine, and if I recall, I can't use foreign key with it.
I am reading mysql documentation but it is still a blur to me. Maybe someone could point me at the right direction?

edit, my table structure is something like this:

```
[group]
group_id, group_description 

[group_hide]
group_id, user_id, hide
```

I want to select all groups that are under "group" table. Except the ones that are hidden inside the group_id table. How can I do this? Right now I can make it either only select all records inside the group_hide table (which is not what I need), or just all records inside group, ignoring all that is in group_hide. I would like it not to select groups that are supposed to be hidden, but everything else should be visible.

Comment: MyISAM doesn't enforce foreign keys so no cascading deletes. But the keys you join on are definitely foreign keys.  Unless your tables have `FULLTEXT` indices or you have some special database backup needs, it's probably worth switching to Innodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can categorize the users and their group visibility somehow, you might consider defining certain "roles". So the associations would be between a role (say "Admin" or "Default" or "Moderator") and the groups, and between roles and users.

E.g. you would create a table `roles` with an ID and a `name`, a table `roles_users` with 2 columns `role_id` and `user_id` and another table `hidden_categories_roles` with 2 columns `hidden_category_id` and `role_id`. Don't forget to put indexes on both columns in both tables to speed up queries.

If the users are so different that they can't  be categorized, your approach is the correct one, and you should simply define indexes on both columns of your new table to speed up queries.

Comment: Hmm ok. When I try to select records with "SELECT item.group_id, hide_group.hide FROM item, hide_group WHERE hide_group.user_id = 'john' AND hide_group.hide = 'true'"
it selects every item and shows hide column as true... How do I make it so that it only shows items that have true flag?

Comment: With this query you are doing an implicit CROSS JOIN, meaning for each entry in "item" you query all rows in "hide_group" with matching criteria (not just those matching the item's group) which is clearly not what you want.I suggest you read up on the different kinds of JOINs and how to perform them. Here's a corrected query that might help you get started: "SELECT item.group_id, hide_group.hide FROM item INNER JOIN hide_group ON hide_group.group_id=item.group_id WHERE hide_group.user_id = 'john' AND hide_group.hide = 'true'"

Comment: By the way, for boolean columns (true or false), you should consider using TINYINT(1) as data type and setting it to either 1 or 0. Using 'true' and 'false' strings is not recommended.

Comment: This didn't get me very far. Still confused a bit. I edited my first post.

Comment: Why is it that when I do "... WHERE hide!='true'" it only shows records that have false flag set, but those with NULL do not show up? This is my main problem right now. Is it because of enum data type?

Comment: If you are performing an INNER JOIN, you are only selecting entries which show up in both tables you're joining, i.e. if there is a group on which there is no information at all in the other table, it will not show up in the result. Once again, I suggest you read up on how the different kinds of JOINs work. A LEFT JOIN may be more suitable for what you want - It shows every row (matching the WHERE conditions) from the table you are joining on, but only those rows which match the join condition from the joined table.